# On Fourier coefficients of Bianchi modular forms, l-ordinary

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $f\in S_2(\Gamma_1(N))$ be a Hecke eigenform and $\ell$ a prime number does not divide $N$. Let $a_f(\ell)$ be the $\ell$-th Fourier coefficient of $f$. Then $a_f(\ell)$ is  is called $\ell$-ordinary if $a_f(\ell)$ is a $\ell$-adic unit.

For any Hecke eigenforms $f$, the Dirichlet density of the following set
$$
\{\ell:\text{ prime numbers }|f \text{ is }\ell\text{-ordinary }\}
$$
is 1. Here are the references:
[Reference Link 1](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ehida/AbNSS.pdf),
[Reference Link 2](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_2002__52_2_351_0/)

Question : Is there the same result for Bianchi modular forms (Automorphic forms on GL(2) over imaginary quadratic fields)?

Comment: Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/390059/6518